# JavaScript Increment Operator isn't working?

Tags: javascript

So for some reason, when I use the increment operator in this code, it doesn't work. I've verified my variables are numbers.. Not sure what's going on.

```
var fs = require('fs')
  , bt = require('buffertools')

var start = 0;

fs.readFile(process.argv[2], function(err, data) {
  console.log(data);
  while (bt.indexOf(data, '\n', start)) {
    var nl = bt.indexOf(data, '\n', start); // nl is 40
    console.log(start, nl); // 0, 40
    console.log(data.slice(start, nl)); // works great!

    start = nl++; // reset the offset past that last character..
    console.log(start, typeof start); // start == 40? the heck? 'number'
    process.exit(); // testing
    //console.log(nl, start); 40, 40
  }
});
```

EDIT ------

And the solution...

```
"use strict";

var fs = require('fs')
  , bt = require('buffertools');

fs.readFile(process.argv[2], function(err, data) {
  var offset = 0;

  while (true) {
    var nl = bt.indexOf(data, '\n', offset);
    if (nl === -1) break;
    console.log(data.slice(offset, nl));
    offset = ++nl;
  }

  console.log(data.slice(offset));
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: `nl++`.  What this does is increment `nl` and return the *original* value.  Try `start = ++nl`.  `++nl` will increment `nl` and return the *new* value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for `++nl` and not `nl++` , `num++` increments the number and returns the *old value*.

- `num++` is the [postfix increment operator](http://es5.github.io/#x11.3.1) - as you can see, its description says "Return oldValue."
- `++num` is the [prefix incremenet operator](http://es5.github.io/#x11.4.4) - as you can see, its description says "Return newValue."

This is true in many other languages too by the way.

---

Since you're not changing `nl` later at all, you can write this as:

```
    start = nl + 1;
```

Which is clearer.

Comment: Interesting. I've never run into that before, thanks. Will accept in 12 minutes.